# resetting an ssd (connected via USB) with kali

Tags: ssd, virus, kali-linux, reset, virus-removal

Ok so long story short I got a virus in my PC running win10, and ended up deciding that resetting the ssd (m. 2) would be the best option... The problem is that it won't let me do so from windows. I therefore decided that I would try to reset it from a PC running kali live. So I buy a m.2 to USB adapter, plug it in the kali pc. At this point I check the disk manager and it appears even if I am unable to interact with it. I then try gparted but it doesn't find the ssd...
At this point I am out of ideas and need help. Thanks

Comment: Windows 10 install can format your disk. But you need to tell us what you mean by "reset" because there is no such term in relation to hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

Download the current Windows 10 ISO file from the Media Creation Link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Use the link that says Make a USB for another computer.

Use Rufus to make a bootable USB key, install the ISO on this bootable key, and start with the Key.

You may need to disable Secure Boot in order to start with it.

You may need to reinitialize the disk with fdisk to start it fresh with no partitions.

If all else fails, you may need to replace the drive.

Comment: I tried this method and the windows installer does recognize the disk and let's me format it, but it does not allow me to install windows on it because it says that the disk partition is GPT.

Comment: The method outlined works with a good disk (starting fresh) and I have used it. Get the manufacturer's disk test app and check your drive. It may not be good or may need an fdisk format to reinitialize it.

Comment: I tried to a alizé the health of the disk with two different programs. The first one said that no information was available, and the second one didn't even find the disk...

Comment: It may be your drive needs to be replaced.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help. But just out of curiosity, can a virus phisically damage a disk? (or in any case render it unusable)

Comment: Not usually but there does appear to be some damage if you cannot initialize the drive and use it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "resetting" ?

If you mean "format" (you will lose all your datas) here is a solution from Kali OS :

1. Open terminal (CTRL + ALT + T)
2. Type `sudo fdisk -l`, you should see something like `Disk /dev/sdX: YGo` where X is a letter and Y the size of you disk in GB/TB.
3. If you see it, you can format it with the command sudo `mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdX`

Kali probably doesnt't have the NTFS module, you could have to run `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`

If you mean "resetting Windows", meaning reinstalling it brand new, if you can still boot on Windows :

1. Open start menu
2. Open the menu with Shutdown/reboot/etc...
3. Press SHIFT and click on Reboot while holding the key
   It will go on recovery options so you can "reinstall" a fresh Windows !

Else, plug back your M.2 inside and plug a USB with Windows installer as John said on another answer

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried to use sudo fdisk but it wound find the drive... And unfortunately I am unable to boot into windows...